# Save GridView scroll state when using fragments

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, fragment

I have a baseactivitiy and have 2 Fragments A and B.

A contains a GridView, if I scroll and press a item Fragment A gets replaced by Fragment B. Now i press the back and Fragment A comes to the screen, but the GridView is not at the same position as it was when I switched to Fragment B.

Here is how i replace fragments

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment inputFragment,String tag)
{       
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 

    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,inputFragment,tag)
    .addToBackStack(tag)
    .commit();
}
```

onCreate event of my Fragments

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

onCreateView event

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.home_page, null);

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
            //do work 
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getFirstVisiblePosition()` when your Fragment stops and save this value. When your Fragment starts again, if this value is set, call one of the following to position that item on screen:

- `setSelection()`
- `smoothScrollToPosition()`
- `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()`

If you use `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()`, then you'll also want to save the Y offset of the first visible item. You can get that by doing the following:

```
View child = gridView.getChildAt(0);
int offset = child.getTop();
```

Then use the saved first position and the saved offset when calling `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset)`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. is it possible to save whole fragment state and prevent re-create itself ?

Comment: Possibly, but this may or may not retain the state of your GridView. Give it a try, and if that's not enough then you can try using the ideas I've suggested.